# How to make os.mkfifo and subprocess.Popen work together?

Tags: python, subprocess, patch, fifo

I'm trying to redirect a **patch** command output using a named pipe. I tried like this:

```
fifo = os.path.join(self.path, 'pipe')
os.mkfifo(fifo)
op = os.popen('cat '+ fifo)
proc = Popen(['patch', current_keyframe, '--input='+fpath, '--output='+fifo], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
os.unlink(fifo)
print op.read()
```

But my script stops at *Popen()* call just like **patch** command didn't completed. How I can make it work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't waiting for the patch command to finish before you read from the fifo. Replace the `subprocess.Popen()` call with `subprocess.call()`, and remove the stdin/stdout redirections you aren't using. Also, use `open(fifo)` to read from the fifo, not `os.popen('cat ' + fifo)`.

You realize, I hope, that you can avoid the FIFO entirely? After `p = Popen(['patch', '--input', fpath], stdout=PIPE)`, you can just read patch's output from p.stdout.

Comment: patch command doesn't return its result to stdout, that's the problem. But thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Right, the default with patch is to replace the file you're patching. If you say `--output=-` patch very helpfully replies `patch: **** can't output patches to standard output`.

Comment: Hm, and here I thought patch was useful. (I'll leave the egg on my face in the original post :)